# C#_How to Multiply elements between Two string

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

-I have two string(non-space):

```
string input1 = "bike2car5ship86plan3";
string input2 = "car382bike50ship92yoyo2";
```

-I've tried *regular expressions* `Match` and *Linq*, but my result is not like hoping:

-How to make them like this result:

> ```
> Bike      2    x  50   =  100 
> Car       5    x  382  = 1910 
> Ship      86   x  92   = 7912
> -----------------------------
> Total                  = 9922
> ```

Note: `plan3` and `yoyo2` does *not appear* in *both* `input1` and `input2` so they *don't enter* the result written.

Comment: What have you tried and where are your problems?

Comment: Why `Car 5 x 38 = 190`, not `Car 5 x 382 = 1910`?

Comment: "I've tried Matches and LinQ" please post these attempts, and we can start from there

Comment: And how is 2x50 110?

Comment: please extract the wording from the string till no occurs, and store it in a list or in dictionary. and for your possilbes..

Comment: @Carra, a special kind of math.. probably the reason that a computer gives the "wrong" results :)

Comment: So sorry! wrong code and then i Edited correctly. Help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *Linq* and *regular expressions*, something like this:

```
string input1 = "bike2car5ship86plan3";
string input2 = "car382bike50ship92yoyo2";

var inputs1 = Regex
  .Matches(input1, "([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .ToDictionary(match => match.Groups[1].Value,
                match => int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value));

var inputs2 = Regex
  .Matches(input2, "([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .ToDictionary(match => match.Groups[1].Value,
                match => int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value));

TextInfo textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

var data = inputs1
  .Where(pair => inputs2.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
  .Select(pair => new {
    Name = textInfo.ToTitleCase(pair.Key),
    Quantity = pair.Value,
    Price = inputs2[pair.Key],
    Total = pair.Value * inputs2[pair.Key], })
  .ToArray();

string table = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data
  .Select(item => string.Format("{0,-5} {1,3} x {2,3} = {3,4}",
     item.Name, item.Quantity, item.Price, item.Total)));

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  table, 
  new string('-', 25), 
  string.Format("Total = {0}", data.Sum(pair => pair.Total)));

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  Bike    2 x  50 =  100      
  Car     5 x 382 = 1910       
  Ship   86 x  92 = 7912    
  -------------------------
  Total = 9922
```

Comment: wow thanks man! i'll try it right now. you are always answer my question well!

Comment: excute me. i got this erro:
`$"{item.Name,-5} {item.Price,3} x {item.Quantity,3} = {item.Total,4}"));`
`$"Total = {data.Sum(pair => pair.Total)}");`
--Unexpected character '$'
--Invalid expression term ')'
I added libary LINQ, REGEX and Globalization.

Comment: @Hung Nguyen: Ah! You don't have **C# 6.0**, Let me change it into `string.Format()`: `$"Total = {data.Sum(pair => pair.Total)}"` -> `string.Format("Total = {0}", data.Sum(pair => pair.Total))`

Comment: i searched gg. And i understood it. Thanks man againt! i'm using C# 3.0 :)

Comment: @Hung Nguyen: Next time, please, *specify the restrictions*: C# 3.0 and alike

Comment: Ok. i'm careless.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple regex, but you have to do it in multiple steps:

1. separate every occurrence of **word+number**
2. separate the **number** from **word**
3. compare and multiply the findings

To step 1:

as regex you can use `"[a-zA-Z]*\d*"`

`[a-zA-Z]*` allows any number of characters followed by a number (`\d*`)

To step 2:

you can separate the number from the name also with regex (`"\d*"`)

To step 3:

you can add the Matches from the first string to a dictionary like:

`myDictionaryForString1.Add(name, value);`

and then multiply the values with your values from the second string (same procedure as for the first string to get the values) like:

```
if (myDictionaryForString1.ContainsKey(name)) {
    myResultDictionary.Add(name, myDictionaryForString1[name] * value);
}
```

Comment: first time i just could code your step1 and step2. i will try step 3. i'm a beginer so they could take 2 weeks :D thanks man!!!